# When we are designing an API service which is returning json string, should we use ensure_ascii=False or ensure_ascii=True?

Tags: python, json

I was wondering, if we were designing an public API service which is returning a JSON string, should we use

`json.dumps(result, ensure_ascii=False)`:

```
{"code": "YE-MA", "name": "Ma’rib"}
```

or

`json.dumps(result, ensure_ascii=True)`:

```
{"code": "YE-MA", "name": "Ma\u2019rib"}
```

Which is more correct, and why?

Comment: The entire purpose of `ensure_ascii` is to provide a 7-bit safe representation for the cases where the recipient lacks the capability to understand raw UTF-8.

Comment: Do u mean ensure_ascii will be easier to consume by legacy system? But, does it come with cost like more resource required for parsing? If the clients are limited to modern Android device, is ensure_ascii still required?

Comment: If you're using Flask, for example, you'd ideally `jsonify` the dictionary to a Response object , not dumps it, however the output would depend on what client is responsible for parsing it

Comment: Not so much the device as the programmer's competence and the robustness of the libraries they use, I suspect. The difference in bandwidth is reasonably clearly visible in your question (though note that the UTF-8 encoding of `\u2019` is two bytes, not one; if you are communicating a lot of Asian text, many code points will require 5 bytes in UTF-8). In some sense UTF-8 is probably easier to handle transparently (the incompetent programmer often won't even realize that it's not straight ASCII) as long as everyone uses the same encoding. (Windows clients would be a different kettle of fish.)